# MVC 5 IValidatableObject not displaying error message?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following ScottGus blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3) - The Basic requirement I have is that I have two text fields on screen - I want to validate if both of them are blank and Sumite button is pressed I want to display to use that one or the other is required

I have a UserModel as below:

```
public class UserViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Account Number:")]
    public string UserAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public bool UserHasName()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName);
    }

    public bool UserHasAccountNumber()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserAccountNumber);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!UserHasName() && !UserHasAccountNumber())
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please enter an Account Number or Name ", new [] {"UserName"});
        }
    }
}
```

On My view I have:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "UserName" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Within Webconfig I have the following :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

However when I hit submit button with both fields blank no error message is displaying on screen?

**Update**

Within Bundle config I am also using jQuery.validate.unobtrusive:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
```

Although afterwards I include js for bootstrap and kendo ui - could that be causing some conflict?

**Updated Two**

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult UserDetails()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // IsValid is true so code goes in here when text fields are blank??
            //redirect to another view
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I do have a JsonValididationFilterAttribute class - code as below - although as I say for some reason breakpoint on Validate or this OnActionExecuting is not being hit?

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        var errorMessages = actionContext.ModelState.Values
            .SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Errors);
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Json.Encode(errorMessages));
    }
```

Comment: Are you check your model (ModelState.IsValid) in controller?

Comment: @idlerboris - yeah I check for ModelState.IsValid - however on breakpoint submitting the form with Blank fields IsValid is true and also if I set a BreakPoint in the Validate Method in ViewModel it does not get hit?

Comment: Can you attach your controller code?

Comment: Are you using a custom modelbinder?

Comment: @idlerboris - question updated again

Comment: Can you ensure the @Html.ValidationSummary(true) enabled?. Also, can you check the console and see any script error in the page?

Comment: Is your textbox in a BeginForm()?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - yeah it is - using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myForm"})) - I can see my controller method being hit but ModelState.IsValid is true which I cannot understand and the breakpoint in the Validate method in model isnt getting hit :/ :/

Comment: NB - there is an at symbol in front of the using in above comment - SO is giving error if I try to put two in a comment...

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat, you should insert your model name in action parameter: ActionResult UserDetails(UserViewModel model)

Comment: @idlerboris - yes, good point.  Without that, the model does not bet bound and Validate will not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should insert parameter in your action method, like this:

```
public ActionResult UserDetails(UserViewModel model)
```

Otherwise, MVC didn't understand, that you want to call `Validate` on this model.

Answer (score 0):

You might need some additional javascript:

include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

You can find it at NuGet Packages: `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`.